# No handlers could be found for logger "thrift.transport.TSocket"

Tags: python

I use command: `os.system("simple_switch_CLI --thrift-port 40000 < s1-commands.txt > /dev/null")`

There's wrong that `No handlers could be found for logger "thrift.transport.TSocket`
I use python2.7
could anyone help me

Comment: But when I open a terminal and run this command, there is no error. When I put it into python and call the os.system() method, I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

osquery require the following package to work :

```
thrift>=0.10.0
pylint>=1.4.3
twine>=1.5.0
wheel>=0.24.0
setuptools>=15.0
future
```

if python 2.7 can't support those you will need to migrate to python 3.XX kernel and start the installation from scratch.

otherwise you call try to update osquery using

```
pip install --upgrade osquery
```